# Why do my lights not show up on my render?

Tags: light

I'm new to blender and my spotlights don't seem to be rendering. I'm using Blender 2.80 EEVEE and none of my lights seems to be showing up. I have some materials that have a bright emission and they're the only ones that appear. Any idea what could be causing this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit: Link to the file - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uj3xP9KGa8t3QJMq4hFzz7WsgOX9BiXS?usp=sharing

Comment: please provide blend file

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of **hidden** objects **intersecting** each other and they are **gigantic**.  Look at the first image, I had to zoom out a lot to see those objects. You need to clean up your scene, organize your outliner and delete what you don't need.

Note that hidden objects (eyeball icon) are only hidden in the viewport.  The camera icon will hide an object during a render.

[image]

[image]